# React - save bytearray from API to xlsx file

Tags: reactjs, mobx, filesaver.js

So the question is simple, how can I save bytearray from API to xlsx file?

I have tried using FileSaver.js and saveAs method but unfortunatelly I haven't managed to acomplish it.
When I try to save data that I get from API using Postman option to save response and I save it as xlsx file the data is being saved correctly but when I try to save using React and FileSaver.js I only get rubbish data (bytearray data from the API).

The code snippet for saving:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
    saveAs(blob, "test.xlsx");
```

If there is any other npm package that could do this functionality please suggest it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure it is important, but your file extension is `xls` not `xlsx` in the example.

Comment: that was a typo, but still I can't make my Blob convert data to type I wrote in that example.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with it: The solution for me was to pass the "responseType: 'blob'" to the apiClient and not to create a new blob directly in the index.js file. Here is my client method that accesses the backend:

```
    loadStockTemplate = async () => {
    return await withDataErrorHandler(api.get(this.stockTemplateRessource, {
        responseType: 'blob'  // important information!
    }));
}
```

This method is loaded in another method (which is executed onclick) in my frontend's index.js file, which looks like this:

```
const downloadExcelTemplate = async () => {

        apiClient.loadStockTemplate().then(response => {
            const filename = 'StockTemplate.xlsx';
            let href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = href;
            link.download = filename;
            link.click();
            
            // cleanup
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
        })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

For me, this approach has worked very well.